# jQuery UI Sortable: Updating hidden input value for each item with new position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

Working with jQuery UI sortable to move around a list of items, and trying to update their positions in form field values.  I can't figure out how to update a hidden input value for each item with its updated position number.  All of the 'currentposition' values should change on each move.  And the position numbers happen to be displayed in **reverse order** on the page.

```html
<div id='sort-list'>
  <div id='listItem_4'>
    ITEM 4
    <input class='originalposition' type='hidden' name='item[4][origposition]' value='4'>
    <input class='currentposition' type='hidden' name='item[4][currposition]' value='4'>
  </div>
  <div id='listItem_3'>
    ITEM 3
    <input class='originalposition' type='hidden' name='item[3][origposition]' value='3'>
    <input class='currentposition' type='hidden' name='item[3][currposition]' value='3'>
  </div>
  <div id='listItem_2'>
    ITEM 2
    <input class='originalposition' type='hidden' name='item[2][origposition]' value='2'>
    <input class='currentposition' type='hidden' name='item[2][currposition]' value='2'>
  </div>
  <div id='listItem_1'>
    ITEM 1
    <input class='originalposition' type='hidden' name='item[1][origposition]' value='1'>
    <input class='currentposition' type='hidden' name='item[1][currposition]' value='1'>
  </div>
</div>
```

The item[#][currposition] value should be changed to the new updated position number for all items.  The position value for each item should be updated, and have the correct value when the form is submitted.  And the positions will be compared to the orginal values on submission.

The closest I have gotten so far is something like:

```js
$(function() {
    $( '#sort-list' ).sortable({
        update : function () { 
            var result = $('#sort-list').sortable('toArray');
            $('input.positioncurrent').each(function() {           

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: note that asker wants items to be displayed in reverse order.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use the `stop` event to update the position when the sort ends.

What I did is, when the sort ends, you retrieve the list of inputs you want to update and their numbers, and for each one you update the new position. The [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method provides the current index of the element in the list as an argument.

```
$(function() {
    $( '#sort-list' ).sortable({
        stop: function () {
            var nbElems = inputs.length;
            $('input.currentposition').each(function(idx) {
                $(this).val(nbElems - idx);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJnDR/)

Comment: That does exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't the [update event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) a better fit for this?

Comment: @Mark I guess it would work too, I don't remember exactly why but at that time I had issues with `update()` not being as reliable as `stop()` or called multiple times maybe.

Comment: This is a old post but is helping me right now. I am running in to and issue where everything is ordered from the bottom up. When looking at the jsfiddle for this the bottom listing is number 1 and the top is 4. When reordering, the bottom listing wil always be current position 1. Is there a way to reverse this as a orderable list would be 1 on top and 4 on bottom? Thanks!

Comment: Was giving errror with var nbElems = inputs.length;
so I removed and just replaced $(this).val(nbElems - idx); with $(this).val(idx-1); 
Working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow command below:

```
let oldSort = $('.field_list').sortable('toArray');
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $( '#sort-list' ).sortable({
        stop: function () {
            $('input.currentposition').each(function(idx) {
                $(this).val($(this).index('input.currentposition') + 1);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).